# Scipy interp2d interpolate masked fill values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I want to interpolate data (120*120) in order to get output data (1200*1200).

In this way I'm using [`scipy.interpolate.interp2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp2d.html).

Below is my input data, where 255 corresponds to fill values, I mask these values before the interpolation.

[image: Input data]

I'm using the code below:

```
tck = interp2d(np.linspace(0, 1200, data.shape[1]),
               np.linspace(0, 1200, data.shape[0]),
               data,
               fill_value=255)
data = tck(range(1200), range(1200))
data = np.ma.MaskedArray(data, data == 255)
```

I get the following result:

[image: Output data]

Fill values have been interpolated.

How can I interpolate my data without interpolate fill values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with [scipy.interpolate.griddata](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) but I'm not sure that's the best one.

I interpolate data with the `nearest` method parameter which returns the value at the data point closest to the point of interpolation.

```
points = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1200, data.shape[1]),
                     np.linspace(0, 1200, data.shape[0]))
points = zip(points[0].flatten(), points[1].flatten())
xi = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1200), np.arange(1200))
xi = zip(xi[0].flatten(), xi[1].flatten())

tck = griddata(np.array(points), data.flatten(), np.array(xi), method='nearest')
data = tck.reshape((1200, 1200))
```

[image: Output data]